# Spyder Crash: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'prompt_toolkit.enums'

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder, prompt-toolkit

My Spyder (version 4.0) crashed and `spyder --reset` has no use. I tried `conda update spyder` and then when I open Spyder in the Anaconda Prompt, it would show these:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Anaconda\Scripts\spyder-script.py", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "E:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\start.py", line 205, in main
    mainwindow.main()
  File "E:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 3748, in main
    mainwindow = run_spyder(app, options, args)
  File "E:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 3623, in run_spyder
    main.setup()
  File "E:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 945, in setup
    from spyder.plugins.ipythonconsole.plugin import IPythonConsole
  File "E:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyder\plugins\ipythonconsole\plugin.py", line 46, in <module>
    from spyder.plugins.ipythonconsole.widgets import (ClientWidget,
  File "E:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyder\plugins\ipythonconsole\widgets\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .debugging import DebuggingWidget
  File "E:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyder\plugins\ipythonconsole\widgets\debugging.py", line 15, in <module>
    from IPython.core.history import HistoryManager
  File "E:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\__init__.py", line 56, in <module>
    from .terminal.embed import embed
  File "E:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\terminal\embed.py", line 16, in <module>
    from IPython.terminal.interactiveshell import TerminalInteractiveShell
  File "E:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\terminal\interactiveshell.py", line 19, in <module>
    from prompt_toolkit.enums import DEFAULT_BUFFER, EditingMode
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'prompt_toolkit.enums'
```

But I could not `conda install prompt_toolkit.enums` because it showed:

```
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - prompt_toolkit.enums

Current channels:

  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

And `prompt_toolkit` has been reinstalled by me. But there was still nothing useful.
I just add the output of `conda list prompt_toolkit` as follows:

```
# packages in environment at E:\Anaconda:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
prompt_toolkit            3.0.5                         0
```

Anybody who can help me? Please!!! I am just wanting to use Spyder normally!

Comment: Versions: Windows 10, python 3.7, conda 4.8.3, Spyder 4.0

Comment: It would be helpful for us if you could edit your question and add the output of `conda list prompt_toolkit`

Answer (score 3):

Maybe your **prompt_toolkit** version is too high, which is incompatible with your **ipython** version.
You can try install **prompt_toolkit 2.xx**.